# Get history version component's render result

Tags: 2011-sp1, componentpresentation

We want to have the history version component's publish result and wondering whether any Tridion API can support our needs.

As one example, we have a HTML component, after publish, the componentpresentation render result at broker DB is


## Hello My friends


It is version 1.

After couple of days, the component content be updated and re-published. The componentpresentation render result at broker DB become:


## Hello Everyone!!


It is version 2.

After that, if we call the API TridionPresenter.GetComponentContent(string componentTcmId, string templateTcmId), we can get the latest result, version 2's render result.

Is there any way we can still extract the version 1's render result out?

Best regards,
Qiang

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to version published item in the broker db. But that's why you should have a separate broker for each environment: tridion_broker_dev, tridion_broker_qa, tridion_broker_prod

On the content manager side, it does keep version. So you can always revert the version from the CM side and publish it out to your selected destination

Comment: Then as a plan B, is it possible we use core service, get one history version at content manager side, then render it by ourselves without publish?

Comment: That's correct. You can use CoreService api to interact the content from the CM side